# Using Multiprocessing to process watchdog queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-watchdog

I am trying to use multiprocessing to process multiple watchdog events at once. 
I am working from code I found here [Python parallel thread that consume Watchdog queue events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632643/python-parallel-thread-that-consume-watchdog-queue-events)

The problem I am having in the code below is in the `load_queue()` `pool.apply_aysync(print_func, (event,))` doesn't execute the `print_func()` function and I can't figure out why. Any help would be great.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
import datetime
import shutil
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading

Incoming_Data = 'D:/Incoming_Data/'

class RMTNET_File_Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self,queue):
        FileSystemEventHandler.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def process(self, event):

        self.queue.put(event)

    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created

        self.process(event)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print('{0} -- event {1} off the queue...'.format(now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), event.src_path))



def print_func(event):

    time.sleep(5)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('{0} -- Pulling {1} off the queue...'.format(now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), event.path))

def load_queue(watchdog_queue):

    while True:
        if not watchdog_queue.empty():
            event = watchdog_queue.get()
            pool = Pool()
            pool.apply_async(print_func, (event,))
            print('Finish load_queue')
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    watchdog_queue = Queue()

    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = RMTNET_File_Handler(watchdog_queue)

    # set observer to use created handler in directory
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=Incoming_Data)
    observer.start()

    worker = threading.Thread(target=load_queue, args=(watchdog_queue,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    print('About to start observer')
    worker.start()





    # sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

observer.join()
```